# Sharepoint Timeline

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am using Sharepoint Online. I am trying to make my tasks appear in the timeline, however they don't. I have tried pressing `add to timeline` in all different ways, nothing shows up.

My startdate is the standard startdate that Tasks create itself, but I have removed and recreated the column Due Date to a Calculated Value.

When I try to add to timeline I do not get an error, it is just that nothing happens.

I have Googled a bit and some Microsoft employee said you were supposed to delete the timeline view, and recreate it, however I did not find out how to do this, since Time Line isn't a VIEW at all, but just "is there".

Answer (score -1):

I believe the advice was to delete the view on which the timeline is based. That is, if you have All Tasks view with Timeline above it, you need to delete All Tasks view and recreate it.

Comment: This answer is a good way to lose the ability to display the timeline altogether.